# Sum case statement in oracle SQL Group By Case description remove nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle18c

| account | DR_DESCRIPTION | CR_DESCRIPTION | DR_AMOUNT | CR_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx-111-xxx | land |  | 60 |  |
| xxx-111-xxx | cash |  | 21300 |  |
| xxx-111-xxx | capital |  | 1789 |  |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | diesel |  | 480 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | gas |  | 19687 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | food |  | 1193 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | water |  | 1789 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | electricity |  | 0 |

I have the following result set of a query

However, what I would like to do is remove the nulls and make the results look like this:

| account | DR_DESCRIPTION | CR_DESCRIPTION | DR_AMOUNT | CR_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx-111-xxx | land | diesel | 60 | 480 |
| xxx-111-xxx | cash | gas | 21300 | 19687 |
| xxx-111-xxx | capital | food | 1789 | 1193 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | water |  | 1789 |
| xxx-111-xxx |  | electricity |  | 0 |

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT account,
    CASE WHEN debit_credit  = 'DR' THEN DESCRIPTION END dr_description,
    CASE WHEN debit_credit  = 'CR' THEN DESCRIPTION END cr_description,
    SUM(CASE WHEN debit_credit = 'DR' THEN income_amount END) DR_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN debit_credit = 'CR' THEN income_amount END) CR_amount
FROM xxxxx
GROUP BY account, CASE WHEN debit_credit = 'DR' THEN DESCRIPTION END, 
    CASE WHEN debit_credit  = 'CR' THEN DESCRIPTION END
```

Comment: there is no indication that land/diesel, cash/gas, or capital/food should be tied together. If you can share some example source data from the `xxxxx` table that you are using, then it may be possible to help.

Comment: hi lemme get that for you right away @EJEgyed

Comment: @EJEgyed i have added the raw data above

Comment: the raw data still doesn't show any relationship between the debits and the credits. How is it that you know the "land DR" should be in the same row as the "diesel CR"? Why can't the "land DR" and the "water CR" be in the same row?

Comment: i know there is no relationship but the presentation of the data requires it to be side by side. i would just like guidance on strategies i can use to get it side by side  @EJEgyed

Comment: the reason why is because the debits dr needs to balance the credits cr ... when u sum up both u need to get back the same amount @EJEgyed

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: i have placed all of that above @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff first table above is the result from the group by query, the second table is what i would actually want to get out of the database. and the third table is the raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to fix your current query:

```
select account,
       max(case when debit_credit = 'DR' then DESCRIPTION end) as dr_description,
       max(case when debit_credit = 'CR' then DESCRIPTION end) as cr_description,
       sum(case when debit_credit = 'DR' then income_amount end) as DR_AMOUNT,                                                 
       sum(case when debit_credit = 'CR' then income_amount end) as CR_amount
from  xxxxx
group by account;
```

The above returns one row per account.  If you want each debit and credit individually, then you would use `row_number()`.  Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering:

```
select account,
       max(case when debit_credit = 'DR' then DESCRIPTION end) as dr_description,
       max(case when debit_credit = 'CR' then DESCRIPTION end) as cr_description,
       sum(case when debit_credit = 'DR' then income_amount end) as DR_AMOUNT,                                                 
       sum(case when debit_credit = 'CR' then income_amount end) as CR_amount
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account, debit_credit order by <ordering column>) as seqnum
      from xxxxx x
     ) x
group by account, seqnum;
```